# Можно ли использовать клиент от Github для работы со своим Git Server

Tags: git

Небольшая группа разработчиков ведет разработку продукта и нужен контроль версий. Денег купить аккаунт на github нет, держать код на бесплатном аккаунте нет желания. Решили поставить Git на свой сервер. Разработчики работают на Windows и Mac OS.

1. Можно ли использовать клиент от Github для работы со своим git сервером?
2. Если нельзя, посоветуйте хороший клиент для работы со своим git сервером для Mac и Win.

Пользоваться командной строкой не можем по соображениям эстетики.

Comment: А бесплатные приватные репозитории на `bitbucket` рассматриваются?

Comment: пока что не рассматриваются. ищу ответы на свои вопросы )

Comment: Во многие IDE встроен клиент к различным системам контроля версий.

Comment: командная строка - самое оно. Гуевые приблуды есть, но с ними постоянно чудеса - к пример, в source tree я уже видел три баги, две связаны с отображением дерева веток. TortoiseGit тупит в проводнике при большом кол-ве файлов. Kraken - мало того, что выглядит страшно, хитроплатный и отображал теги как отдельные коммиты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub клиент можно использовать только с GitHub. Но для git сервера(включая и GitHub) можно использовать любой клиент. Сам использую консоль но мои знакомые используют TortoiseGit.

Не знаю зачем вам свой git сервер. Как указали в комментариях есть же bitbucket.

Для использования приватных реп GitHub-а могу предложить вам использовать [GitHub для студентов](https://education.github.com/pack)(если кто то из команды студент). Регистрация проста и даёться не ограниченое количество приватных реп и участников этих реп.

Comment: А я вот не могу представить, зачем отказываться от своего git-сервера. Это и скорость, и надежность (пока стабильность интернета зависит от пьяного экскаваторщика), и приватность (что актуально для бизнеса).

Comment: @ГерманБорисов не уж вы думаете что сможете показать скорость и надёжность лучшую чем bitbucket? А что касается бизнеса то для него актуально отдать денюжку и не парится по поводу сервера.

Comment: Скорость и надежность цепи определяется самым слабым звеном. И то и другое тут интернет. Арендованный сервер оправдан если нет возможности всех разработчиков подключить к локалке.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов топикстартер пишет "Денег купить аккаунт на github нет", но вы думаете, что у него есть деньги на полноценный сервер с raid и систему резервного копирования? Наиболее вероятно, что упомянутый "свой сервер" - это домашний комп одного из разработчиков. То есть он не обеспечит ни доступность, ни сохранность данных, ни доступность самого сервера. В контексте заданного вопроса, bitbucket или gitlab является гораздо более разумным решением. А для крупного бизнеса, конечно же свой сервер актуален.

Comment: Для команды до 20 человек вполне хватает расшаренной папки в локалке. Резервное копирование и так делает каждый участник на своем компе. Еще раз повторяю, слабым звеном тут является интернет, а не сервер.

Answer (score 0):

На официальном сайте git'а приведен список из 13 популярных клиентов под Mac. https://git-scm.com/download/gui/mac.
Большинство из них работают и под Windows.

Но сначала я бы порекомендовал инструменты, идущие в комплекте поставки git'а - git-gui и gikt.

PS лично мне под Windows нравится TortoiseGit